# How to validate all properties of an object in go-swagger?

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, go-swagger

I have a swagger.json which accepts a POST body as an object with some required properties with data types.

I can see the **ServeError()** being invoked when either of the properties is missing or if one is a wrong data type. *It stops and gives the first validation which fails*.

Is there any way to validate **ALL** the properties, so when **Serve
Error** is invoked it has details about all the validations which failed?

I'm hoping there's a flag I can put in the swagger.json, haven't been able to find it anywhere it.

```
"postResp": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "RecordId", "SomeString"],
  "properties": {

      "RecordId": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
     "SomeString": {
        "type": "string"
      }

  }
}
```